# Fix file load error in PowerShell: 'file is not utf-8 coded'

Tags: file, jupyter-lab, powershell-remoting, powershell-cmdlet, windows-terminal

The file load error keeps popping up after I added contents to the file by using commands.

I was working on Windows PowerShell on JupyterLab. Firstly, I created a new file using the following command:

```
New-Item -Path "test.txt"
```

I managed to open the file and type down a few lines directly into it.

However, after I tried to add some content to the file using the command:

```
echo abc >> test.txt
```

I can not open the file by clicking on its symbol any more. The file load error keeps popping up every time I try to do so.

`File Load Error for test.txt`

`C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts\Git\test\test.txt is not UTF-8 encoded`

However, it is still possible for me to get the content from the file using the command:

```
Get-Content test.txt
```

Can someone please shed some light on my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your text editor may be changing the text file's encoding when you save it.

If you're using Notepad to edit the text file, make sure you set the encoding to `UTF-8` in the Save As dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you suggest solutions to the problem?